# Is OneToMany UNI with JoinColumn possible?

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following OneToMany UNI mapping with JoinColumn:

[image]

But in [JPA wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) I read this is wrong and in case of JoinColumn an inverse relationship is required. I can't understand why. My code works. Where's the catch?

```
If the OneToMany uses a foreign key in the target object's table JPA requires that the
relationship be bi-directional (inverse ManyToOne relationship must be defined 
in the target object), and the source object must use the mappedBy 
attribute to define the mapping.
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid. Just strange that a post knows about its author in the table, but not in the entity. BTW, the javadoc has an example doing exactly that: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html. The wikibook is wrong on that matter.

Comment: Maybe what wikibook really meant was this is available in JPA 2.0 only

Comment: 1-n fk relations are valid in ALL jpa versions!

Answer (score 0):

@JoinColumn on @OneToMany was introduce in JPA 2.0 before this was not possible.

Performance tip:

According to the Hibernate commiter Vlad Mihalcea it's better to use a bi-directional realtionship:
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/